# Haskell Input Output

Tags: haskell, input, io, output

Is it possible using's Haskell's input and output to be able to capture and store user entered data into variables?

For example if user was asked a question:

Enter your firstname: Ben, 
then firstname = Ben, 
Enter your surname: Davies, 
then surname = Davies

And finally a print statement to concatenate the 2 variables ie. firstname ++ surname = Ben Davies?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Enter your first name"
   firstName <- getLine
   putStrLn "Enter your last name"
   lastName <- getLine
   putStrLn $ "Your full name is " ++ firstName ++ " " ++ lastName
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's easy to do that. See [this example](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html)